# How to prepopulate fields in Reference Dialog box?

Tags: entities

There is a similar thread [Prepopulate a field in a Reference Dialog Box](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129426/prepopulate-a-field-in-a-reference-dialog-box)
I would like to grab from the node its author name, values of several fields and to prepopulate fields in the references dialog box with them. Is it possible to do?

Reference Dialog is displayed via iframe so getting the nid from the URL won't work.